# $T^{00} ≠ $ Hamiltonian Density?

Tags: electromagnetism, hamiltonian-formalism, classical-field-theory

Check page 48-49 of http://walterpfeifer.ch/qft/QFT5.pdf?. It is apparent that the Hamiltonian **density** of the Maxwell Field is not positive definite when expressed in terms of the Four-vector Potential $A^\mu$, even if the total Hamiltonian corresponds to $$\int \frac{1}{2} (\vec{E}^2 +\vec{B}^2)d^3x$$
Why is it that when the Gauge Potential is used, we end up with a Hamiltonian Density which isn't equal to $\frac{1}{2} (\vec{E}^2 +\vec{B}^2)$ ? Most importantly, does this mean that the Hamiltonian Density does not necessarily correspond to the $T^{00}$ energy-momentum tensor (since the energy momentum tensor must be gauge-invariant?)

Comment: I'm not sure but the stress-energy tensor used in your document is $T^{\mu\nu}=\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \partial_\nu A_\sigma}\partial^\mu A_\sigma-g^{\mu\nu}\mathcal{L}$. In order to have the right stress energy tensor one has to add $\partial_\lambda \Psi^{\mu \nu \lambda}$, where $\Psi^{\mu \nu \lambda}=\frac{1}{\mu_0}A^\mu F^{\nu \lambda}$. Then you recover the expression given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor).